# 20.04 No Bluetooth found - rfkill won't list bluetooth but /init.d/bluetooth status shows its running

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, 20.04, iwlwifi

### Issue:

I'm running a dual boot installation of Ubuntu 20.04 in a HP SPECTRE 360.
It has an Intel Wireless-AC 9462 wireless card that drives both WiFi and Bluetooth on the same package (card).

The problem is that Bluetooth won't turn on. It says that no Bluetooth device has been found.

[image: Bluetooth not found]

---

### Tried solutions:

I've tried to update the iwlwifi driver as specified in [here](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi) using the most updated version from the [Linux firmware repository tree](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git) but nothing changes. I however don't know if just replacing the file in the `/lib/firmware/` directory is enough or I do have to recompile the driver.

At first I downloaded the driver from [Intel's Linux Wireless support website](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html) and it comes with a README file that includes some installation instructions on it in which mentions that some kernel configurations have to be made since it uses the *kernel's firmware_class infrastructure*.
I've tried to follow those instructions but I have not been able to find much documentation on how to access the locations it mentions.
README file contents:

```
Intel Wireless WiFi Link 9000 AC Adapter
Copyright (C) 2017 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Microcode Package README.iwlwifi-9000-ucode

INDEX

1. OVERVIEW
2. INSTALLATION
3. LICENSE


1. OVERVIEW

The files iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.ucode provided in this package
must be present on your system in order for the Intel Wireless WiFi Link
AGN driver for Linux (iwlwifi) to operate on your system.

The "-34" in the filename reflects an interface/architecture version number.
It will change only when changes in new uCode releases make the new uCode
incompatible with earlier drivers.

On adapter initialization, and at varying times during the uptime of
the adapter, the microcode is loaded into the memory on the network
adapter.  The microcode provides the low level MAC features including
radio control and high precision timing events (backoff, transmit,
etc.) while also providing varying levels of packet filtering which can
be used to keep the host from having to handle packets that are not of
interest given the current operating mode of the device.

2. INSTALLATION

The iwlwifi driver will look for the file iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.ucode
using the kernel's firmware_class infrastructure.
More information can be found under Documentation/firmware_class in kernel
source. In order to function correctly, you need to have this support enabled
in your kernel.  When you configure the kernel, you can find this option in
the following location:

        Device Drivers ->
                Generic Driver Options ->
                        Userspace firmware loading support


You can determine if your kernel currently has firmware loader support
by looking for the CONFIG_FW_LOADER definition on your kernel's
.config.

In addition to having the firmware_class support in your kernel, you
must also have a working udev and uevent infrastructure configured.
The steps for installing and configuring udev are very
distribution specific.

Once you have the firmware loader in place (or if you aren't sure and
you just want to try things to see if it works), you need to install
the microcode file into the appropriate location.

Where that appropriate location is depends (again) on your system
distribution.  You can typically find this location by looking in the
udev scripts of your distro, the default is /lib/firmware.

Installation of the firmware is simply:

        % cp iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.ucode /lib/firmware

You can now load the driver (see the INSTALL and README.iwlwifi provided with
the iwlwifi package for information on building and using that driver.)

3. LICENSE

The microcode in this package (iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.ucode) is provided
under the terms of the following license (available in the file
LICENSE.iwlwifi-9000.ucode):

Copyright (c) 2017, Intel Corporation.
All rights reserved.

Redistribution.  Redistribution and use in binary form, without
modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are
met:
 reproduce the above copyright notice and the
  following disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials
  provided with the distribution.
* Neither the name of Intel Corporation nor the names of its suppliers
  may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software
  without specific prior written permission.
* No reverse engineering, decompilation, or disassembly of this software
  is permitted.

Limited patent license.  Intel Corporation grants a world-wide,
royalty-free, non-exclusive license under patents it now or hereafter
owns or controls to make, have made, use, import, offer to sell and
sell ("Utilize") this software, but solely to the extent that any
such patent is necessary to Utilize the software alone, or in
combination with an operating system licensed under an approved Open
Source license as listed by the Open Source Initiative at
http://opensource.org/licenses.  The patent license shall not apply to
any other combinations which include this software.  No hardware per
se is licensed hereunder.

DISCLAIMER.  THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND
CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING,
BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT,
INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING,
BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS
OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND
ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR
TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE
USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH
DAMAGE.
```

---

### backport-iwlwifi-dkms

I've also noticed that the *Software & Updates* indicates that it is not using the 3rd party driver and that the device is not working as shown in the following image:
[image: Software & Updates screen shot]

I tried installing `backport-iwlwifi-dkms` driver using the package manager *Synaptic* to solve the issue and it would then show the driver working
[image: Software & Updates screen shot after backport-iwlwifi-dkms installation]

However I still won't be able to detect the Bluetooth card and the WiFi signal becomes really really slow. won't be able to access any website.

---

### Complementary information:

If I check the service status it says that Bluetooth is running but it won't show on my settings menu.

`$ /etc/init.d/bluetooth status`

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-02-08 18:21:07 MST; 6h ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 706 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18704)
     Memory: 2.3M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─706 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

feb 08 18:21:07 criopc systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
feb 08 18:21:07 criopc bluetoothd[706]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
feb 08 18:21:07 criopc systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
feb 08 18:21:07 criopc bluetoothd[706]: Starting SDP server
feb 08 18:21:07 criopc bluetoothd[706]: Bluetooth management interface 1.17 initialized
```

`$ rfkill`

```
ID TYPE DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 1 wlan phy0   unblocked unblocked
```

`$ hciconfig scan`

```
Can't get device info: No such device
```

`$ sudo bluetoothd -n -d`

```
bluetoothd[32304]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
bluetoothd[32304]: src/main.c:parse_config() parsing /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
bluetoothd[32304]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “DiscoverableTimeout” in group “General”
bluetoothd[32304]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “AlwaysPairable” in group “General”
bluetoothd[32304]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “PairableTimeout” in group “General”
bluetoothd[32304]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “Privacy” in group “General”
bluetoothd[32304]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “Name” in group “General”
bluetoothd[32304]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “Class” in group “General”
bluetoothd[32304]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “DeviceID” in group “General”
bluetoothd[32304]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “ReverseServiceDiscovery” in group “General”
bluetoothd[32304]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have group “GATT”
bluetoothd[32304]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have group “GATT”
bluetoothd[32304]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have group “GATT”
D-Bus setup failed: Name already in use
bluetoothd[32304]: Unable to get on D-Bus
```

`$ systemctl | grep -i blue`

```
  bluetooth.service 
                  loaded active     running   Bluetooth service
```

`$ dmesg | grep -i blue`

```
[    3.230744] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.230758] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.230761] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.230763] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.230765] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.291545] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.4 build 0 week 30 2018
[    3.292551] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 2
[    3.292552] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[    3.292553] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[    3.292553] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[    3.292554] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[    3.292555] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[    3.299515] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-19-0-4.sfi
[    6.203820] Modules linked in: snd_soc_dmic x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof intel_powerclamp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi coretemp ledtrig_audio snd_soc_core mei_hdcp kvm_intel snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine kvm intel_rapl_msr snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_hda_codec crct10dif_pclmul snd_hda_core ghash_clmulni_intel snd_hwdep aesni_intel crypto_simd snd_pcm cryptd glue_helper snd_seq_midi rapl nouveau(+) snd_seq_midi_event intel_cstate snd_rawmidi snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer iwlmvm input_leds snd efi_pstore wmi_bmof intel_wmi_thunderbolt btusb hp_wmi serio_raw btrtl i915(+) mxm_wmi ee1004 soundcore ttm btbcm btintel uvcvideo hid_sensor_magn_3d mac80211 hid_sensor_accel_3d hid_sensor_incl_3d videobuf2_vmalloc bluetooth videobuf2_memops hid_sensor_gyro_3d drm_kms_helper hid_sensor_rotation videobuf2_v4l2 libarc4
[    6.204341] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0xfc09 tx timeout
[    6.473051] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    6.473052] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    6.473055] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   13.390194] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to send firmware data (-110)
[   13.390236] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-19)
[   13.390255] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel reset sent to retry FW download
[   19.487425]  bluetooth videobuf2_memops hid_sensor_gyro_3d drm_kms_helper hid_sensor_rotation videobuf2_v4l2 libarc4 hid_sensor_trigger videobuf2_common industrialio_triggered_buffer kfifo_buf hid_sensor_iio_common industrialio videodev cec iwlwifi ecdh_generic ucsi_acpi rc_core ecc mc i2c_algo_bit mei_me joydev fb_sys_fops processor_thermal_device cfg80211 mei hid_multitouch syscopyarea typec_ucsi intel_rapl_common cros_ec_ishtp sysfillrect cros_ec mac_hid sysimgblt intel_soc_dts_iosf typec int3400_thermal intel_hid acpi_thermal_rel sparse_keymap hp_wireless int3403_thermal acpi_pad int340x_thermal_zone sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 usbhid hid_sensor_custom hid_sensor_hub intel_ishtp_loader intel_ishtp_hid hid_generic nvme i2c_i801 rtsx_pci_sdmmc crc32_pclmul i2c_smbus nvme_core thunderbolt intel_lpss_pci intel_lpss rtsx_pci idma64 ahci xhci_pci intel_ish_ipc virt_dma libahci xhci_pci_renesas intel_ishtp i2c_hid hid wmi video pinctrl_cannonlake
[10662.439683]  bluetooth videobuf2_memops hid_sensor_gyro_3d drm_kms_helper hid_sensor_rotation videobuf2_v4l2 libarc4 hid_sensor_trigger videobuf2_common industrialio_triggered_buffer kfifo_buf hid_sensor_iio_common industrialio videodev cec iwlwifi ecdh_generic ucsi_acpi rc_core ecc mc i2c_algo_bit mei_me joydev fb_sys_fops processor_thermal_device cfg80211 mei hid_multitouch syscopyarea typec_ucsi intel_rapl_common cros_ec_ishtp sysfillrect cros_ec mac_hid sysimgblt intel_soc_dts_iosf typec int3400_thermal intel_hid acpi_thermal_rel sparse_keymap hp_wireless int3403_thermal acpi_pad int340x_thermal_zone sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 usbhid hid_sensor_custom hid_sensor_hub intel_ishtp_loader intel_ishtp_hid hid_generic nvme i2c_i801 rtsx_pci_sdmmc crc32_pclmul i2c_smbus nvme_core thunderbolt intel_lpss_pci intel_lpss rtsx_pci idma64 ahci xhci_pci intel_ish_ipc virt_dma libahci xhci_pci_renesas intel_ishtp i2c_hid hid wmi video pinctrl_cannonlake
[11076.839944]  bluetooth videobuf2_memops hid_sensor_gyro_3d drm_kms_helper hid_sensor_rotation videobuf2_v4l2 libarc4 hid_sensor_trigger videobuf2_common industrialio_triggered_buffer kfifo_buf hid_sensor_iio_common industrialio videodev cec iwlwifi ecdh_generic ucsi_acpi rc_core ecc mc i2c_algo_bit mei_me joydev fb_sys_fops processor_thermal_device cfg80211 mei hid_multitouch syscopyarea typec_ucsi intel_rapl_common cros_ec_ishtp sysfillrect cros_ec mac_hid sysimgblt intel_soc_dts_iosf typec int3400_thermal intel_hid acpi_thermal_rel sparse_keymap hp_wireless int3403_thermal acpi_pad int340x_thermal_zone sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 usbhid hid_sensor_custom hid_sensor_hub intel_ishtp_loader intel_ishtp_hid hid_generic nvme i2c_i801 rtsx_pci_sdmmc crc32_pclmul i2c_smbus nvme_core thunderbolt intel_lpss_pci intel_lpss rtsx_pci idma64 ahci xhci_pci intel_ish_ipc virt_dma libahci xhci_pci_renesas intel_ishtp i2c_hid hid wmi video pinctrl_cannonlake
[11099.615987]  bluetooth videobuf2_memops hid_sensor_gyro_3d drm_kms_helper hid_sensor_rotation videobuf2_v4l2 libarc4 hid_sensor_trigger videobuf2_common industrialio_triggered_buffer kfifo_buf hid_sensor_iio_common industrialio videodev cec iwlwifi ecdh_generic ucsi_acpi rc_core ecc mc i2c_algo_bit mei_me joydev fb_sys_fops processor_thermal_device cfg80211 mei hid_multitouch syscopyarea typec_ucsi intel_rapl_common cros_ec_ishtp sysfillrect cros_ec mac_hid sysimgblt intel_soc_dts_iosf typec int3400_thermal intel_hid acpi_thermal_rel sparse_keymap hp_wireless int3403_thermal acpi_pad int340x_thermal_zone sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 usbhid hid_sensor_custom hid_sensor_hub intel_ishtp_loader intel_ishtp_hid hid_generic nvme i2c_i801 rtsx_pci_sdmmc crc32_pclmul i2c_smbus nvme_core thunderbolt intel_lpss_pci intel_lpss rtsx_pci idma64 ahci xhci_pci intel_ish_ipc virt_dma libahci xhci_pci_renesas intel_ishtp i2c_hid hid wmi video pinctrl_cannonlake
[19485.449869]  bluetooth videobuf2_memops hid_sensor_gyro_3d drm_kms_helper hid_sensor_rotation videobuf2_v4l2 libarc4 hid_sensor_trigger videobuf2_common industrialio_triggered_buffer kfifo_buf hid_sensor_iio_common industrialio videodev cec iwlwifi ecdh_generic ucsi_acpi rc_core ecc mc i2c_algo_bit mei_me joydev fb_sys_fops processor_thermal_device cfg80211 mei hid_multitouch syscopyarea typec_ucsi intel_rapl_common cros_ec_ishtp sysfillrect cros_ec mac_hid sysimgblt intel_soc_dts_iosf typec int3400_thermal intel_hid acpi_thermal_rel sparse_keymap hp_wireless int3403_thermal acpi_pad int340x_thermal_zone sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 usbhid hid_sensor_custom hid_sensor_hub intel_ishtp_loader intel_ishtp_hid hid_generic nvme i2c_i801 rtsx_pci_sdmmc crc32_pclmul i2c_smbus nvme_core thunderbolt intel_lpss_pci intel_lpss rtsx_pci idma64 ahci xhci_pci intel_ish_ipc virt_dma libahci xhci_pci_renesas intel_ishtp i2c_hid hid wmi video pinctrl_cannonlake
[20140.483603]  videobuf2_vmalloc bluetooth videobuf2_memops hid_sensor_gyro_3d drm_kms_helper hid_sensor_rotation videobuf2_v4l2 libarc4 hid_sensor_trigger videobuf2_common industrialio_triggered_buffer kfifo_buf hid_sensor_iio_common industrialio videodev cec iwlwifi ecdh_generic ucsi_acpi rc_core ecc mc i2c_algo_bit mei_me joydev fb_sys_fops processor_thermal_device cfg80211 mei hid_multitouch syscopyarea typec_ucsi intel_rapl_common cros_ec_ishtp sysfillrect cros_ec mac_hid sysimgblt intel_soc_dts_iosf typec int3400_thermal intel_hid acpi_thermal_rel sparse_keymap hp_wireless int3403_thermal acpi_pad int340x_thermal_zone sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 usbhid hid_sensor_custom hid_sensor_hub intel_ishtp_loader intel_ishtp_hid hid_generic nvme i2c_i801 rtsx_pci_sdmmc crc32_pclmul i2c_smbus nvme_core thunderbolt intel_lpss_pci intel_lpss rtsx_pci idma64 ahci xhci_pci intel_ish_ipc virt_dma libahci xhci_pci_renesas intel_ishtp i2c_hid hid wmi video
[22202.986802]  videobuf2_vmalloc bluetooth videobuf2_memops hid_sensor_gyro_3d drm_kms_helper hid_sensor_rotation videobuf2_v4l2 libarc4 hid_sensor_trigger videobuf2_common industrialio_triggered_buffer kfifo_buf hid_sensor_iio_common industrialio videodev cec iwlwifi ecdh_generic ucsi_acpi rc_core ecc mc i2c_algo_bit mei_me joydev fb_sys_fops processor_thermal_device cfg80211 mei hid_multitouch syscopyarea typec_ucsi intel_rapl_common cros_ec_ishtp sysfillrect cros_ec mac_hid sysimgblt intel_soc_dts_iosf typec int3400_thermal intel_hid acpi_thermal_rel sparse_keymap hp_wireless int3403_thermal acpi_pad int340x_thermal_zone sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 usbhid hid_sensor_custom hid_sensor_hub intel_ishtp_loader intel_ishtp_hid hid_generic nvme i2c_i801 rtsx_pci_sdmmc crc32_pclmul i2c_smbus nvme_core thunderbolt intel_lpss_pci intel_lpss rtsx_pci idma64 ahci xhci_pci intel_ish_ipc virt_dma libahci xhci_pci_renesas intel_ishtp i2c_hid hid wmi video
```

`$ lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9b61 (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0c)
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Thermal Subsytem
00:13.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Integrated Sensor Solution
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 02ed
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 02ef
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9462
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Serial IO I2C Host Controller
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Serial IO I2C Host Controller
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Management Engine Interface
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode]
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02ba (rev f0)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02bc (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02b0 (rev f0)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02b4 (rev f0)
00:1d.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02b6 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0284
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 02c8
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 02a3
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake SPI (flash) Controller
01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
03:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
03:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
03:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
04:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 NHI [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
3a:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
3b:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX250] (rev a1)
3c:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Intel Corporation Device 0975 (rev 03)
3d:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Intel Corporation Device 0975
```

`$ lspci -k -s 00:14.3`

```
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9462
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9462
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

`$ lsusb`

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 06cb:00bb Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b67b Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HP Wide Vision FHD Camera
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1bcf:053e Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 2.4GHz 2way RF Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: You probably mean Ubuntu 19.10 (ie. the 2019-October release of Ubuntu), but please clarify or correct; there was no 2019-January release of Ubuntu.

Comment: That is correct, 19.10

Comment: Did bluetooth work on another version or OS?

Comment: @Jeremy31 I booted up from Ubuntu 18.04 in a live USB and it did worked

Comment: You may want to edit your DBus policy to allow access to 'org.bluez' client. Take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170118/dbus-systembus-policies)

Comment: Is package `bluez` on your System?

Comment: @nobody Yes it is installed in my system

Comment: @ParsaMousavi I do think that may be the solution, I just don't have the "/etc/dbus-1/system.config" file. I do have 2 files that may be relevant:
"/etc/dbus-1/system.d/avahi-dbus.conf"
"/etc/dbus-1/system.d/bluetooth.conf"

Comment: thats, why I ask if bluez is on your system.  Please reinstall package bluez.

Comment: @nobody I've purged it and reinstalled it, nothing has changed

Comment: so blind `cat /etc/bluetooth/main.conf`

Comment: I have the same problem with my HP Spectre x360 and the same wireless. Any solutions yet?

Comment: @farshadnia Only solution so far is sell your HP computer and never buy one again for Linux usage. They openly claim don't design computers intended for Linux and they offer no support whatsoever. I guess the other solution is to develop a driver (My level of expertise is not that pro yet). Or put pressure on Intel so they revision their drivers and fix that bug.  But I'm pretty sure that it may have to do with the fact that both services (WiFi and Bluetooth) use the same bus I believe. My guess is while WiFi is active it may lock the bus keeping the Bluetooth services from using it

Comment: @MarcoCastro I feel you; it has been a battle (against Optane, Secure Boot, etc) to even boot into Ubuntu on this machine. But I am happy with the speed, fan noise (compared to Windows), privacy, and other gains to do so. I guess I'll pay $10 for a usb bluetooth dongle for now and hope for the developers to catch up with these latest technologies soon.