# No system.config file

Tags: system, dbus

I've been having problems with the d-bus permissions and I believe is because I don't have a the `/etc/dbus-1/system.config` file. 
I'm using Ubuntu 19.10. How can I get this file? and why is it not there? I'm I suppose to create it or it should've been created during my Ubuntu installation process?

Comment: AFAIK the standard location is `/usr/share/dbus-1/system.conf`, and the  `/etc/dbus-1/` location is provided for local overrides. What problems are you having exactly, and why do you believe that they are due to a missing `/etc/dbus-1/system.config` file?

Comment: the problem I'm having is that my system won't enable Bluetooth. a clue is that by running `bluetoothd` I would get the following error: "D-Bus setup failed: Connection ":1.1201" is not allowed to own the service "org.bluez" due to security policies in the configuration file". You can find more information in the following question https://askubuntu.com/questions/1206004/no-bluetooth-found-d-bus-setup-failed

Comment: That's just because you were attempting to run the daemon as a non-privileged (non-`root`) user I think - honestly, it sounds like you are going down the wrong rabbithole here